# Reusable Sub Workflows?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I am in process of developing Class library of Sub workflows; I have set of Activities which I use for creating Sub workflow. I want to develop these sub workflows as reusable workflows which I can use in creating actual workflows. I am basically implementing Class Library of existing workflows which can be used by others to create actual business workflows. What I want is when user creates one Sub workflow it should be automatically should be added in Class library of workflows and compiled and should be available as reusable component at run time.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify this.

Comment: Will To clarify further; What I am looking for is develop Workflows which are very granular and developed by developers. And those would be used by other users as components. It like Custom Class Library developed by Framework developers which can be leveraged by every other developers...

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand your goals, however it isn't as easy as you believe it should be.

The first instinct is to add an Activity to your solution (Add => New Item => Workflow => Actvity), and drag other Activities onto the design surface.

This will create reusable workflows, unfortunately they will not have any Designer associated with them.  So, when another user attempts to drag these workflows from the toolbox and use them in a workflow in a different solution, they'll get something like this:

[image: designer fail]

That isn't exactly useful.  An alternative is to create a custom Activity that implements [IActivityTemplateFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.iactivitytemplatefactory.aspx).  This type (I believe*) can be added to the Toolbox.  When they are dragged onto the design surface, the [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473817.aspx) method is called.  Within this method, you can construct whatever workflow you want and return it.  This activity tree will be added to the workflow so that all activities within it are visible.

*You may also have to extend Activity in order for it to show in the Toolbox; I'm not sure about that.  Think of the Activity being a dummy which actually is never used.

Answer (score 0):

This may also be useful

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwinkle/archive/2009/12/24/swiss-cheese-and-wf4-or-an-introduction-to-activityaction.aspx

> One common scenario that was often
>   requested by customers of WF 3 was the
>   ability to have templated or “grey
>   box” or “activities with holes” in
>   them (hence the Swiss cheese photo
>   above).  In WF4 we’ve done this in a
>   way that way we call ActivityAction